# Page designs to prevent redundant+identical e-commerce orders

Tags: php, javascript, e-commerce

noob question: I'm building a checkout system for an online commerce site. I'm getting the bug where clicking on the "place order" button multiple times will place the order multiple times. I have an idea to load between the button-click page and place-order page with a page that waits several seconds before launching using javascript the place-order page.

My question is: what are some of the policies online for dealing with this particular scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended practice is to:

- Include a unique id on the order page
- Disable the order button once it has been clicked
- Check for the unique id in your serverside processing (make sure to handle race conditions)

There are lots of specific details to consider, but these heavily depend on your platform/framework of choice.